# Best way of adding "different than" zero validation attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, attributes

What is the best way of adding "Different than zero" validation attribute in ASP.NET MVC 3/4?

Comment: I wonder why's the -1 on my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume you would want to add a custom validation attribute with the error message "Different *than* zero" (not sure of the correct English usage here). Say you have a model with a property that requires the validation:

```
public class YourModel
{
    [Required]
    [CheckZero] //custom attribute
    public int PropertyName { get; set; }   
    ...
}
```

Create a class `CheckZeroAttribute` that derives from `ValidationAttribute` and override one of the `IsValid` methods provided by the base class. Overriding the `IsValid` version taking a `ValidationContext` parameter provides more information to use inside the `IsValid` method (the `ValidationContext` parameter will give you access to the model type, model object instance, and friendly display name of the property you are validating, among other pieces of information).

```
public class CheckZeroAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid (object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
         //the error message
         string sErrorMessage = "Different from zero";
         //implement appropriate validation logic here
         ...
         if (...) { return new ValidationResult(sErrorMessage); }
         return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```